# how to integrate plastic scm with jira?

Tags: version-control, jira, issue-tracking, plasticscm

I am trying to migrate from VSS to Plastic SCM and want to use it with JIRA.

I have reached this far.

[image]

I tried referring to their help documentation. but that did not help.

Does someone know how to link a new branch to an issue in JIRA ?

I tried to giving same name to Issue and Branch. That din't work.
If the Issue key is : "DEMO-7",  what should be the "Branch Prefix" & "Branch Name" in Plastic SCM ?

I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: I have reached the point where I can click details of a branch and go to JIRA issue. This indicated that branch and issue are now linked.
I still need to know how to see history of changesets from JIRA though.
All tabls are empty in JIRA even when I have made several check-ins to the branch.

Comment: For the changeset jira log, make sure you are having the custom Jira field well configured in the Jira side.

Comment: it worked. the problem was, the scope of custom field was only for a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue key is DEMO-7 and the branch prefix you are using is "DEMO" you just need to name you branch as "DEMO007".